# EncryptedRandomAccessFile

Tags: java, security, stream, randomaccessfile

Is there anything like an `EncryptedRandomAccessFile` in Java? That's how I'd call it, but the name seems to be too innovative as I couldn't find anything. Basically, it should implement `DataInput`, `DataOutput`<sup>1</sup> and provide a `seek` method.

I guess, all it needs is wrapping `RandomAccessFile` with a seekable stream cipher, but as security should be done by experts only, I'm resisting the attempt.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm aware that overwriting data would be a security risk and need the output for appending only.

Comment: you realize that most encryption schemes don't allow partial updates or appends?

Comment: @jtahlborn That could be the reason why I haven't found anything. I don't care about integrity, just privacy. I could live without appends, if necessary, what I mainly need is to seek and read.

Comment: Wrap a DataInputStream over a CipherInputStream and use `skip()`.

Comment: @jtahlborn Do we bet that skipping forward means decrypting everything in between and skipping backward is unsupported?

Comment: yes indeed.  as i already alluded to, most encryption schemes can not be partially read.  you _have_ to start at the beginning and decrypt to the data you need.  if you want to go backward, you need to store all the previously decrypted info, or start from the beginning again.

Comment: if you need to skip around in the data, just decrypt the whole thing, do whatever you need to it, and then re-encrypt it.

Comment: You can, of course, split the file into blocks. Say around the size of a sector. Restart the encryption from there, probably incorporating the offset. Block mode encryption has its weaknesses. (NB: I am not a cryptographer.)

Answer (score -2):

This may help you: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html
I dont know too much about security but I know the basics, give it a try.

Comment: Forget it, it's completely unrelated.

Comment: Use Utf-8 or other standar